# Denying Access To A Page Based On Referrel

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

Here's where I'm at:

1. I have a Wordpress plugin that allows for subscriptions to be in place, and uses the Paypal IPN. This plugin denies access to certain pages based on whether a user has an active subscription.
2. I have another plugin that allows for one time payments for a different service. This takes the user to Paypal, and redirects them to a page where they can upload videos. These videos can only be uploaded after payment, but anyone can access the page by direct URL...

How can I limit access the this upload page?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure if you want to do this with JavaScript or PHP... PHP would be more reliable (people can turn off JavaScript,) but ultimately, the referrer can be altered by a user if they are really keen to bypass any measures you put in place, so bear that in mind when implementing this.

The best way would just be to have an if statement checking the referrer, and if it isn't an acceptable referrer, just redirect them.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JAVASCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
<!-- Hide script from old browsers
if (document.referrer != '[Only Allowed Referrer URL]')
{
    window.location = "http://not.allowed.to.view.site";
}
//-- Stop hiding script -->
</SCRIPT>
```

or

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] != "[Only Allowed Referrer URL"])
{
    header( 'Location: http://not.allowed.to.view.site' ) ;
}

?>
```

I haven't fully tested the above code, but something like that is what you want. Basically, if it isn't from an "allowed" referrer, redirect to an error page.

Again, using the referrer URL to deny or grant access to a page isn't that reliable, but if you want to do it, something like that is what you need. Also be wary of things such as the URL may sometimes have "www." at the beginning, sometimes may not. There may be variations of the URL that you will want to consider in your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using something like this in your paypal form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mydomain.com/verify.php">
```

If so, in this page: `http://mydomain.com/verify.php` you must verify if the transactions was right. [Instant Payment Notification - Code Samples](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/pdt-codesamples-pop-outside#php) stuff, correct? Well, if this verification is invalid you deny all further processing (uploading video).

Otherwise you redirect to let's say `http://mydomain.com/upload.php`:

```
header('Location: http://mydomain.com/upload.php') ;
```

Now, in the uploading page you put at top:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://mydomain.com/verify.php')
{
    die('get out of here!');
}
```